# get parents node value of struts2 jquery tree tag

Tags: struts2, tree, jstree, struts2-jquery

I am new in struts 2 and jquery

I want to get the all parents of the leaf child in action class I am not understand How can i get all the parent node value in the Action class.

If there is any other example instead of `[https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/TreeTag][1]`

then Please share with me.
Thanks

Comment: Anyone downvoted after down vote please tell me the solution of the problem .....

Comment: Show what you have so far.

Comment: I want to get the parent of checked child and unable to get that and one more when my tree is loaded then it is load with checked node from database.